# Remove characters from specific point until before space using sed or awk

Tags: macos, awk, sed

I would like to remove characters from a specific point until just before the first whitespace (without removing the whitespace itself). For instance, my file.txt is as follows: -

```
>DN256845_c2_g1_i1 len=56274 ACGGAGG
>DN256532_c0_g2_i19 len=23973 AATACTC
>DN256979_c8_g3_i32 len=16728 CGAAACT
```

'X' are numbers such as 1 or 19 or 32 and I would like it to be: -

```
>DN256845_c2_g1 len=56274 ACGGAGG
>DN256532_c0_g2 len=23973 AATACTC
>DN256979_c8_g3 len=16728 CGAAACT
```

I had used `sed 's/_i.*//'` but it removed everything after `_i`. Other codes that I had tried were `sed 's/_i.*\./\ /g'`,
`sed -E 's/_i.*+[^[: :]]//g'` which ended-up with nothing changed.

How do I solve this using sed/awk or any other approach? I appreciate the help. Thanks!

EDIT: As suggested by Sundeep, I edited the problems for ease of understanding. This data are actually Trinity transcripts identifier. I need to remove the identifier (_i1 and so on) for some analysis).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In awk:

```
$ awk '{sub(/_[^_ ]+ /," ")}1' file
>DN256845_c2_gXX len=56274 ACGGAGG
>DN256532_c0_gXX len=23973 AATACTC
>DN256979_c8_gXX len=16728 CGAAACT
```

Same with `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/_[^_ ]\+ / /' file
```

*Replace the first instance of an underscore, everything but an underscore or a space and a space with a space.*

**Edit:** I wonder why I didn't post this obvious awk manipulating the end of $1:

```
$ awk '{sub(/_[^_]+$/,"",$1)}1' file
```

Comment: Or just `sed 's/_i[^ ]*//' file`  (or more generally, `sed 's/_i[^[:space:]]*//' file`)

Comment: Sure, TIMTOWTDI.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! Now I'm just curious how it worked.

Comment: The explanation is in italic.

Comment: Good tip of using first field then it became much easier, like this for instance: awk '{sub(/_i.*/,"",$1)}1' file

Answer (score 1):

> 'X' are numbers such as 1 or 19 or 32

It is a good idea to give sample as close as possible to real use case. I've changed sample data to change `X` after `i` to numbers.. if this doesn't help, please add better sample to question

```
$ cat ip.txt
>DN256845_c2_gXX_i1 len=56274 ACGGAGG
>DN256532_c0_gXX_i19 len=23973 AATACTC
>DN256979_c8_gXX_i32 len=16728 CGAAACT

$ sed 's/_i[0-9]* / /' ip.txt
>DN256845_c2_gXX len=56274 ACGGAGG
>DN256532_c0_gXX len=23973 AATACTC
>DN256979_c8_gXX len=16728 CGAAACT
```

- `_i[0-9]*`  match `_` followed by zero or more numbers followed by space
- replace this with space

For this use case, this could also be shortened to

```
sed 's/_i[^ ]*//' ip.txt
```